# How to determine least common subsumers using the owlapi

Tags: ontology, owl-api, reasoning

Is there an existing way to determine least common subsumers using the OWLAPI?

The least common subsumer of concept descriptions `C_1, ...,C_n` is the most specific concept description `C` expressible in the given DL language that subsumes `C_1, ..., C_n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function specifically doing this, but it's possible to normalise a class expression, so a simple algorithm for getting to the least common subsumer (or approximation thereof) is to create a union and normalise it.

A more sophisticated approach would include a reasoner (e.g., to simplify complex class expressions if it turns out some of them are equivalent between them or if there's a class that already subsumes all the others in the expression).

Comment: Thanks @Ignazio. I suspected as much, but wanted check!